# Perfmon - L2 cache miss per thread

Tags: scheduling, x86-64, perfmon

```
Architecture:
**AMD** Opteron quad-core using 2 CPUs --- Numa system
Each CPU has a shared L3 Cache ; Each Core has a private L1 and L2

Processor : x86_64 Operating System: GNU/Linux
```

I am new the world of [Perfmon](http://perfmon2.sourceforge.net/). I am trying to get the performance counters like `Last level cache misses(LLCM)` and `IPS`.

I am able to fetch them when there is just one thread/core

is it also possible to fetch the performance counters like IPS and LLCM per thread, when there are more than `2 threads/core`?.

From my research - I realized that it is not possible to get LLCM/IPS per thread when there is more than one `thread/core` as AMD does not provide those performance counters.

So, my question is, is it possible to fetch the PC/thread at Level 2 cache. 
if yes - How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I researched about it a little more and asked my professor about it.

It looks like perfmon does allow us to do it.

Hope this helps. Let me know if I can help out in some way.